# Integraing Google Identity Toolkit with GWT app on GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, google-eclipse-plugin, google-identity-toolkit

Using eclipse with the the "google-identity-toolkit" imported, is there no full java option to implement the Identity Toolkit for a GWT app on GAE?  I've read the google docs for Google Identity Toolkit v3, but can't find a clear answer.

This comes very close to answering my question:
[How to integrate Google Identity Toolkit with a single webpage app (e.g. GWT)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31490950/how-to-integrate-google-identity-toolkit-with-a-single-webpage-app-e-g-gwt)